# Generating snapshots of Ajax content for BingBot vs GoogleBot

Tags: ajax, bingbot, noscript

We have a website whose content is generated dynamically via JavaScript. For the purpose of search engine indexing we also provide snapshots of the pages.

Here are some examples:

- https://www.recreyo.com
- https://www.recreyo.com/yangtze-river-cruise-china
- https://www.recreyo.com/beijing-xian-train-china

If you view the HTML source of one of these links, you will notice that there is content specified within `noscript` tags. This is a mirror of the dynamic JavaScript generated content that users will see, and has been put in place for search engine crawlers to process.

Now GoogleBot has correctly processed the `noscript` content and displays them in search results, but BingBot is not indexing the pages.

[Google Results](https://www.google.com/#q=site:recreyo.com)

[Bing Results](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site:recreyo.com&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=site:recreyo.com&sc=1-16&sp=-1&sk=)

I've made sure the sitemap has been submitted and waited for about four days.

How do we solve the problem? Ideally, I'd like to do it the noscript way as it is simple and elegant. Alternatively, I could add the content in standard markup and use CSS to hide it, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible, because that is just unnecessary extra work for the browser.

Does any have any insight into this problem? Specifically, is there any evidence that BingBot will not process content within `noscript` tags?

Comment: It's rather comon to see Bing being slow at indexing... How long has it been since the site went live in its current form? as it takes months to get all pages indexed into Bing, and even then you might not have all indexed (Bing = super picky on deeper pages.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @bybe. It's only been about four days since I submitted the sitemap for the website in its current form. The thing that's worrying me is that Bing has indexed the landing page, but failed to index any of the links, all of which are defined within a noscript tag.

Answer (score 1):

In my cases, I design fully Ajaxified content and found that it is difficult to crawl properly by bots. 
So I redesign it. When pages opened for first time ,the visible content is exactly same as it created using javascript events.In short, each piece of content got their own URL and listed all URLs to a sitemap. Finally, I found most URLs get crawled and indexed.

You can see my site for example: learn.servloci.com

additionally you can check using site:[given url] as its cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised that the `noscript` tags work for Google.   Google released a standard for [crawlable AJAX](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1) where your page has a meta tag that causes the crawler to fetch the snapshot from the URL with an additional parameter on it.

[Bing now support this standard too](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1), so implementing it will get your content indexed in both Google and Bing.